# Throws FileNotFoundException but the files exist

Tags: c#

Though files are exist in the Physical location FileInfo.Length returns an error FileNotFoundExceptions. I would like to inform you that the file is a virtual file. What I have done so far

```
string filePath=@"N:\Orders\SubFolders\group.indd";
FileInfo fileInfo=new FileInfo(filePath);
string modifiedDate = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");                                       
string fileSizeInKB = string.Format("{0:0,0 Byte}", fileInfo.Length);
```

Comment: Does `fileInfo.LastWriteTime` return the correct value without errors?

Comment: It returns a value but not the correct one

Comment: What do you mean by `virtual file`?

Comment: code is correct... might group.innd is not in readable format. Do u installed innd reader

Comment: Virtual file means  the actual location of the file in the network drive but my file system driver shows it in a virtual drive as if it is a Physical file.

Comment: Any chance group.indd is a directory??

Comment: @rashim also please post full stack trace maybe it will give some hint..

Comment: No. There is no change in group.indd

Comment: @Shadow Wizard---The stack trace    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at ABC.FileSystemBrowser.CustomView.ABCTemplateView.GetListViewItems4Files(FileInfo fileInfo, ArrayList fileIconNInfo) in C:\Projects\NET35\ABC.FileSystemBrowser.Solution\ABC.FileSystemBrowser.CustomView\ABCTemplateView.cs:line 1195

Comment: @rashim is this WinForms or ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 0):

The file is marked as Directory, in the low level.

Here is the code inside the get_Length method of FileInfo class:

```
if ((this._data.fileAttributes & 0x10) != 0)
{
    __Error.WinIOError(2, base.DisplayPath);
}
```

The code 2 means "FileNotFound" exception, and the 0x10 code in hex is 16 in decimal.

The FileAttributes enum contains this:

```
//
// Summary:
//     The file is a directory.
Directory = 16,
```

So, what **is** "group.indd"? Never heard of such extension, so can you elaborate what exactly is this?

Comment: Adobe InDesign document? Unsure why it's a directory though, unless it's like an osx .app ...

Comment: @Tim yeah just saw that now.. worth opening this with Notepad and see maybe there's some hint.